# Update image in php and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have to update image in php and mysql database. I know I cannot set the value of file type input field but how do I achieve this?

```
//upload.php
User Image<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/ico" value="<?php echo $_GET['image'];?>" />
```

```
//upload query

    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $fname=$_GET['fname'];
    $lname=$_GET['lname'];
    $image=$_GET['image'];
  $sql = "UPDATE myGuest SET firstname='$fname', lastname='$lname', image='$image' WHERE id='$id'";  
    if($conn->query($sql))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Record updated succesfully')</script>";
        header("Refresh:0; url=view.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
}
```

```
//view.php
<td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>&fname=<?php echo $row['firstname']?>&lname=<?php echo $row['lastname']?>&image=<?php echo $row['image']?>">EDIT</a></td>
```

Comment: Same way as you do with `INSERT` new data.

Comment: Please elaborate on that

Comment: Note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using prepared statements

Comment: I'm aware...I'm new to php and database connectivity. and this is only my homework.

Comment: Even for homework, it's always a good habit to get :). Imagine, you want to insert the name `O'Bryan`, your query will fail because of the single quote

Comment: @Cid Thanks for your suggestion..I'll certainly consider in future

Answer (score 1):

The data type should be `longblob` to insert image in DB.

```
 $image_content = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

Now you can use variable `$image_content` to insert/update image in DB.

To display the image use

```
header("Content-type: image/jpg"); 
echo $row['image'];
```

For more details [Follow this](https://www.codexworld.com/store-retrieve-image-from-database-mysql-php/)