# Show sql datatype image in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the flowing sql query the MainImage datatype is image (think binary)

```
SELECT dbo.tbl.strPartNumber AS SKU, dbo.tbl.strDesc AS ProductName, dbo.tbl.strExtendedDesc AS ShortDesc,
        (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.tblImg.imgData FROM dbo.tblImg WHERE dbo.tblImg.strpartnumber = dbo.tbl.strpartnumber AND bitDefaultImage = '1') as MainImage,
        dbo.tbl.bitInactive AS Inactive FROM dbo.tbl WHERE bitWebstoreItem = '1'
```

now I can get all data to show but not the image
this what I  have for the img  show

what I would like to do is select image from outside datasource  and add it to new or existing product in woocommerce

```
$DefaultImage = base64_encode($row["MainImage"]);
if (isset($DefaultImage) && $DefaultImage !== null) {
    echo '<td align="center" style="border-color:#000000"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $DefaultImage . '" width="150" height="150"></td>';
        } else {
        echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"border-color:#000000\">No image available.</td>";
    }
```

it only shows a broken image

I have search the forum and no solution is found yet

I have done a var_dump and get string(0)

I read the following [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958350/display-image-in-php-page-from-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com) but this is for only the images.

also this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785364/update-image-in-php-and-mysql-database](https://stackoverflow.com)

*****EDIT*****

SCREENSHOT OF DATA
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYlvk.jpg)

Comment: So have you checked what the base64-encoded string looks like? Is it definitely a valid image?

Comment: @ADyson yes I can see that in the database it has data in it? what type I do not know. it is jpeg or jpg, webp, png

Comment: Right... so `data:image/jpeg` is a bit of an assumption then? Try testing it with an image you've prepared and you know is definitely a JPEG. Also I know you can see the data in the database - but if you look again, that wasn't what I asked you.

Comment: @ADyson appologies, the encodes string is empty.

Comment: Ok. That's a bit strange. Are you quite sure that `$row["MainImage"]` contains what you expected, then?

Comment: I have edity qestion wit a screenshot of the data. hopt helps

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errorshttps://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) . Also, the context is unclear. Is that you showing me the data at source in the database? Again, that wasn't what I asked

Comment: @ADyson, sorry for all the missunderstandings. the guy that worked on it has left everything just as it is. I see that the images datatype is image in the database. no one else is willing to handel the project so I was selected?

Comment: Ok. So debug the code and check that `$row["MainImage"]` contained the right data when you ran it. I can't see a reason why [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) would return an empty string (as you told me) unless that $row data was also empty.

Comment: P.S. Your SQL query is pretty strange. Why not just do a JOIN onto the images table and restrict to the default image, instead of the complicated subquery?

Comment: @ADyson, no need to make a join when i call it in a sub select

Comment: My point was that a JOIN is usually more efficient (and certainly more readable)

Comment: I suggest you to debug how the information is being saved on the database. Maybe it makes more sense to save the data as base64 so it can be displayed straightforwardly with the method you have. Otherwise check if the encoding and datatype you're using for that column matches with whatever you're saving. IE: using a varchar to save binary data can cause issues with encoding. I think the issue is more on the "saving" side of the app, not so much on the "reading and showing" side. If the data was properly saved, your method should work.